# Difficulty creating multiple profiles on Microsoft Edge browser in Ubuntu

Tags: user-profile, ubuntu-edge

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to create multiple profiles on the Microsoft Edge browser within Ubuntu. Whenever I try to log in with a different user profile, the browser seems to get stuck and doesn't allow me to proceed.

I've followed the usual steps to create profiles as we do in window os, but I'm consistently facing this problem.

Could someone please guide me through the correct procedure to create and switch between multiple user profiles effectively on Microsoft Edge in Ubuntu? Are there any known workarounds for this issue?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the community. I am not sure this is Ubuntu-related problem.You had better provide more details like where you downloaded Microsoft Edge, what exact steps you have taken and what kind of errors you are getting.

Comment: I follow official document and command to install edge through terminal. I successfully installed as well but when i want to create multiple profile at that time edge stucks. And I won't be able to create multiple profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a long time. Today, I have switched to "Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon" and installed Edge by downloading ".deb" file from [official page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/download?form=MA13FJ).

I could add my first Microsoft account as normal. I have clicked to "Set up new personal profile" and added a new profile.

[SS: Set up new personal profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k07Is.png)

When I try to sign in to my second Microsoft account it opens a floating modal to enter email.

[SS: floating modal to enter email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy7yL.png)

After I enter my email it switches to the other profile (my first Microsoft account) and asks me to enter password there.

[SS: auto-switch to first profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eflYV.png)

Even if I enter my password, it doesn't forward the authentication to other profile so it gets stuck.

[SS: stuck on sign in state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhHb7.png)

**SOLUTION**:
Go to profile settings of new profile.

[SS: profile settings button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkypz.png)

Click "Profile preferences".

[SS: Where is "Profile preferences"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzpFD.jpg)

Here I turned off everything (profile switching options, auto sign in, allow single sign-on, etc.).

[SS: Switches to turn off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTXii.png)

Additionally, I did the same (turning off profile switching and other settings) on my first profile and set the "Default profile for external links" (Profile preferences) to the new profile.

Maybe not all these steps are necessary, but you may just do them temporarily and reset settings after you finish.

Then I could just sign in my second account without any profile switch. There might still be a problem if you are using Microsoft authenticator app to sign in without a password, but it works when I use password. In my case, I have used password and one time code (OTC) from the authenticator as 2FA.

Hope it helps :)